# Certain classes no longer working but show in css and html

Tags: css, wordpress, ssl

Created my first wordpress site and everything was styled and working correctly until today. We added an ssl, switched everything over to https, and since then a couple of my css classes no longer work. Most of them do, but my styling for a specific table on the testimonials page and the media queries for tables no longer work.

When inspecting the html and css on the site, the html shows the classes on the elements and the css file shows the classes and their elements, but the classes are not being applied. [The testimonals page](https://eyealivedrops.com/wordpress/testimonials/) the table with the images and buttons was centered and had the buttons overlapping the images but now none of that shows.

The css for this table is:

```
table.test {
  width: 66%;
  margin: auto;
}
td.nopad {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center !important;
}
td.nopad-btn {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center !important;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

And the html:

```
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td class="nopad"><img src="https://eyealivedrops.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/group-people.jpg" alt="group-people" width="290" height="199"  /></td>
    <td class="nopad"><img src="https://eyealivedrops.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/pets.jpg" alt="pets" width="290" height="199" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nopad-btn"><a href="#people" class="button">People Testimonials</a></td>
    <td class="nopad-btn"><a href="#pets" class="button">Pet Owner Testimonials</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, the site is not displaying these styles on the page and I can't figure out why..

[This is the link to the full css file, in case its something somewhere else](https://eyealivedrops.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/eye-alive/style.css?ver=1.0) Thank you in advance to anyone who looks into this, I've been looking through the Q&A's here and can't find anything else that fits my problem.

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Feyealivedrops.com%2Fwordpress%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Feye-alive%2Fstyle.css%3Fver%3D1.0&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: Can you make the page where the styles are being applied available?  The CSS is great to have, but we need to see the actual page as well.  Your homepage does not have any .test table to see...  The other thing to note, you need to remove http: from your google font calls.  Just have it be //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900

Comment: @Daniel thank you, this is the page with the test table [testimonials page](https://eyealivedrops.com/wordpress/testimonials/)

Comment: @Daniel C you don't *need* to remove the http:, I've never seen an instance where it doesn't work that way; additionally, this is the way the Google documentation tells you to do it.

Sam, have you tried making your CSS selector more specific? To be honest, I'm a little stumped here too, because I see the CSS in your stylesheet, but do not see it being applied, even if overwritten.

Comment: @TaniaRascia You DO need to remove the http to make the page secure.  It's not related to the OP's problem, but it is causing their home page to not be fully secured.  Load the page and check out the lock symbol.  Also, Google documentation tells you to use https.  Again, not related, but I wanted to give the OP a heads up to help keep the page locked proper.

Comment: @TaniaRascia I've tried making the selectors as specific as `div#main-sidebar-container section#main article.post-170.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry section.entry table.test` with no luck, and yes that is exactly what is stumping me!

Comment: @Daniel C Odd, I was looking at the page and I saw it hard coded as https.

Comment: @TaniaRascia https://eyealivedrops.com/ is insecure, not the page with the css problem.  If that helps?

Comment: @Daniel C I only mean that the only place I see Google fonts loaded is `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A100%2C%3A100italic%2C%3A300%2C%3A300italic%2C%3Aregular%2C%3Aitalic%2C%3A700%2C%3A700italic%2C%3A900%2C%3A900italic%7CNunito%3A300%2C%3Aregular%2C%3A700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` Which honestly looks kind of weird, yet...also, the eyealivedrops.com shows up as perfectly secure on my end, so I wonder what that's all about.

Comment: @TaniaRascia Hmmm... that is weird.  I'm seeing this error (1 of 6): Blocked loading mixed active content "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900".  When I look at the source, they have <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> in the <head>.  There are also two images failing on http.  Strange how you see different!  Maybe there is no issue there at all :)

Comment: We're not even seeing the same fonts being loaded...now I'm just confused. :{

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your CSS file...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    table:not(.shop_table.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table, .shop_table.cart {
        display: block

;
}
```

You forgot to close the ), so the rest of your CSS is not loading proper.

It has nothing to do with http or https as it fails in both cases.  You might have more css issues... I'll look further.

**UPDATE**

You also have this error:

```
.product-total {
    padding: 0, 10px, 10px, 10px;
}
```

Should be:

```
.product-total {
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

You have another error here:

```
button.button,
input.button,
a.button,
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {
    background: #AABBD4 !important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#AABBD4, #4873A6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#AABBD4, #4873A6) !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 95%;
}
```

Missing unit of measure on `-webkit-border-radius: 28; -moz-border-radius: 28;` which I assume should be px

Comment: that seems to have fixed everything, thank you so much! I thought it could be that I just missed a character somewhere but couldn't find that.

Comment: No problem... check out my other updates as you have two more errors.

Comment: It might be helpful to run your CSS files through CSS linters (error checkers), or use a text editor with a linting plugin to prevent these types of problems in the future.

Comment: I strongly agreed with Tania on the error checker... I use PHPStorm which has a built in one... look into using a good editor!

Comment: @TaniaRascia definitely, I use notepad++ and even if there aren't any linter plugins for that I will start regularly running my stuff through online ones.

Comment: I would recommend looking into [Brackets](http://brackets.io) - it's available for Windows and Mac and has plugins for everything.